# Buisness layer helper objects

Tags: .net, architecture, business-logic

I have multiple objects that are used by several classes in my BL.

I'm tring to understand how those objects should be instansiated and where to store them.

I don't want to pass them from the Service layer.
My thoughs are to create a singleton class in the BL and all the others would use it.
Is it a reasonable solution? I know many think of the singleton as an anti patten.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use singleton or static. It prevents your class from dependency injected and inflexible. I.e: you cannot change the class behavior based on component.

The best is to use constructor injection:

```
public class Usage{
    public Usage(Component1 comp1, Component2 comp2){ /*param assignment*/ }
    private Component1 comp1;
    private Component2 comp2;

    //using comp1 and comp2
}
```

Or if you think that it is bothersome for object composition, you can use default object creation, that is commonly used by .Net.

```
public class Usage{
    public Component1 Comp1 = new Component1();
    public Component2 Comp2 = new Component2();

    //using Comp1 and Comp2
}
```

The benefit is, you can change `Components` with it's `inheritance`, or you can use interface as declaration instead for better flexibility.

Comment: Completely agree. Don't use static classes. Inject instances and program against interfaces.

Comment: Thank you. But how should I share the usage class between all the different classes in the BL?

Comment: As said, inject them in the components that need them.

Comment: I'll try explaining myself better: I have at least 5 different usage classes and more then 5 Components that I don't want to initialize in each of them. The Components are internal therefore I can't really pass them as Ctor params because the BL classes are created from the service layer. I just can't see how injection is a solution for me.

Comment: @RotemB Honestly you have more complex architecture than the one you described in the question. Unless you can describe it better at your question (code example, etc), there aren't many that can help you

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, we have static Classes that handle some of the shared functionality across the business layers / services. that should not be an issue.

You have to demarcate the correct purpose of those classes and make use of them. If you can provide some use case or find that having a static / singleton as a best fit to your usecase, you can align with that